# The differences between "wanted" and "would want" and "would"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, tense, subjunctives

I'm a non-native speaker. In my mother tongue, we just have one verb to express "willing", so sometimes it's a puzzle to us Persians: **What are the differences among "wanted" and "would want" and "would"?**

For example, what are the differences among these sentences:

1. You wanted to do it.
2. You would want to do it. (I guess it's better to add some words at first of this sentence like "maybe")
3. You would do it.

**Edit:**

There is no problem to me about "want" and "would". my main problem is the difference between these two verb.

What do I know about "Wanted" and "would"?

To me "wanted" and "would" is completely like together and it expresses a willingness in past that is failed.

Comment: I think you ***would*** need to include what you already know. That preceding sentence is a typical use of ***would*** (which could be replaced by present tense ***will*** with no significant change in meaning). In practice, *will, would* aren't often used with any allusions to *willingness, volition* (they're modal verb forms primarily used to convey "future" or "conditionality"). We need to know what you *do* know before we can meaningfully explain those aspects of usage you presumably *don't* know.

Comment: What is your understanding of the meanings of "would" and "want"? In English, "want" isn't exactly the same as "willing", so it's difficult to give you a complete answer that takes into account the verb in your native language without understand more about what you're trying to say in your sentences. "She wanted to" is different from "She was willing to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>1: You **wanted** to do it means that at some point **in the past you were willing** to do it</strike>

2: You **would want** to do it means that I think **you would be willing** to do it if... (you knew what it was / you thought about it differently)

3: You **would** do it means it **isn't always something you are willing** to do but you may do it if...

---

**EDIT:**

**Want** suggests desire, it implies that you are happy to do something, if you want something you'll take measures to get it (trade, buy, steal...)

- I **want** a pony, I'll go out and get one if I can.
- I **wanted** to go to London *but* something stopped me.
- I **would want** to go to Spain *but* I can't afford to.

**Willing** suggests that you will do something, but you might need to be persuaded or paid. It in no way means **want**.

- I am **willing** to look after a pony, *but* I'm not going to try to get one.
- I was **willing** to go to London but I had no reason to go.
- I would be **willing** to go to Spain with you if you **want** to go, otherwise I would not go.

Comment: Per @ColleenV's comments above, *to **want** [to do something]* doesn't exactly mean *to **be willing** [to do it]*. It's perfectly possible to say, for example, *I'm willing to do it, but I don't actually want to*.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers, I've corrected my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'd still say your text conflates ***want*** and ***be willing***. For example, your first definition, for *You wanted to do it,* should be something more like *At some point in the past it was your **wish, desire** to do it*. Saying you were *willing* to do it just means you were *prepared* (perhaps reluctantly, effectively, almost "against your will") to do it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers this is harder than I thought... Though I would say that if you **wanted** to do something you'd also be **willing** to do it by definition. It is only when you **don't want** to do something that you **may or may not be willing**

Comment: You're quite right that the way English uses words in the general area of *desire, obligation* can get pretty "hard". I think that over many generations, native speakers have "deliberately" connived/contrived to blur the distinction between those two meanings in the interests of tact and diplomacy. So we end up today with *He was willing to do it* usually implying *He didn't really **want** to, but in the circumstances, he was **prepared** to do it*. As opposed to *He did it willingly*, which invariably implies he did it enthusiastically (by implication, because he really did want to do it).